# Why multi variable linear regression using Tensor Flow keras gives NaN loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm  trying to build a multi-variable Linear regression NN model.But when i train the model it gives me Loss as NaN. Why does it occur.In case of single variable linear regression i was able to make it work.But in that also for some data sets it gives me NaN as loss.How can i resolve it.

```
   import tensorflow as tf
    import pandas as pd
    from tensorflow import keras
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    dataDF = pd.read_csv('50_Startups.csv')

    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    RangeIndex: 50 entries, 0 to 49
    Data columns (total 4 columns):
     #   Column           Non-Null Count  Dtype  
    ---  ------           --------------  -----  
     0   R&D Spend        50 non-null     float64
     1   Marketing Spend  50 non-null     float64
     2   State            50 non-null     object 
     3   Profit           50 non-null     float64
    dtypes: float64(3), object(1)

memory usage: 1.7+ KB

dataDF.drop(labels='Administration',axis=1,inplace=True)
dummy = pd.get_dummies(dataDF.State)

mergedDF = pd.concat([dataDF,dummy],axis=1)
mergedDF.drop(labels='State',inplace=True,axis=1)
mergedDF.drop(labels='New York',inplace=True,axis=1)

X = dataDF.reindex(columns=['R&D Spend','Marketing Spend','California','Florida'])
y = dataDF[['Profit']]

X.shape
(50, 4)
y.shape
(50, 1)

model = keras.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Dense(units=1,input_shape=[4]),
        keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

model.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(X,y,epochs=100)

Epoch 1/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 2/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 3/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 4/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 5/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: nan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loss is nan because of two reasons.

**1st** -  Too big value such that it cant be stored in a tensor.
**2nd** - Too small value such that it cant be stored in a tensor

Since you just started the training process your case mostly falls in the 1st category.

Therefore try decreasing the learning rate.

start from **lr** = 1e-7 and eventually increase it.

Also Seeing your data its better to normalize the data before linear regression to bring the loss down.

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

train_df = pd.read_csv('data/50_Startups.csv')

labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
train_df['State'] = labelencoder.fit_transform(train_df['State'])
train_labels = train_df.pop('Profit')

scaler = StandardScaler()
train_df = scaler.fit_transform(train_df)

def create_model2():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1,input_shape=[4])])
    
    model.compile(optimizer= 'sgd',
                  loss='mean_squared_logarithmic_error')
    return model

model = create_model2()

model.fit(train_df,train_labels,epochs=100)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 127.6634
Epoch 2/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 125.5097
Epoch 3/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 123.8063
Epoch 4/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 122.2603
Epoch 5/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 120.8088
Epoch 6/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 119.5372
Epoch 7/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 997us/step - loss: 118.3753
Epoch 8/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 998us/step - loss: 117.4335
Epoch 9/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 997us/step - loss: 116.5944
Epoch 10/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 115.5112
```

If I change the loss to 'mean_squared_error'.
Code -

```
model.compile(optimizer= 'sgd',
                  loss='mean_squared_error')
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 13925959680.0000
Epoch 2/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 12734133248.0000
Epoch 3/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 11678848000.0000
Epoch 4/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 10710425600.0000
Epoch 5/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 997us/step - loss: 9848304640.0000
Epoch 6/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 9040133120.0000
Epoch 7/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 997us/step - loss: 8345449984.0000
Epoch 8/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 7684101120.0000
Epoch 9/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 7067404800.0000
Epoch 10/100
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 998us/step - loss: 6524263424.0000
```

As you can see even after normalizing the the loss is huge. So if you train a linear regression model without normalizing the loss will be even greater.

Comment: model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e7),loss='mean_squared_error')  I used like this.But still the loss is NaN

Comment: `1e-7` not `1e7`

Comment: Yeah I changed it to -7 but still it gives NaN

Comment: Can you try `model.compile(optimizer= tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-7),loss='mean_squared_logarithmic_error')`. This will reduce your loss so that it can fit into a variable.

Comment: Can you share your dataset?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220532/discussion-between-aniket-bote-and-stark2022).